# Accessing SqlConnection from a button

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I will try to explain this clearly, so now I got

```
sqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
InitializeComponent();

conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=servername;" +
                        "Initial Catalog=database;" +
                        "Integrated Security=True;";
```

in the MainWindow and I want to fire the command

```
SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
```

when a button is clicked, it's a stupid question now the button can't see `conn` because it's in the MainWindow how can I access it?

The thing is I don't want to reconfigure the connection every time the button is clicked.

Comment: You haven't shown the context of `conn` so we can't tell if it is in scope or not, but your description implies `conn` is decleared at the class (window) level so why can't the button event "see" it? Is the button on a different window?

Comment: you create one class for db connection and invoke the class file when ever you want that is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

This gets the root level window:

```
Window parentWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow
```

or the immediate parent window

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

So access the `conn` property like this

```
if(parentwindow.conn != null)
{
    SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand(query, parentwindow.conn);
}
```